# Cakephp v3.2.10 - error using virtual fields in other entities

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am trying to use "virtual fields" across 3 tables and I just can't get it to work across more than 2.

I have 3 tables

> item_type 
>   project_items 
>   projects

with suitable relationships

```
    $this->table('project_items');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('ProjectTemplates', [
        'foreignKey' => 'project_template_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('ItemTypes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'item_type_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

I have a virtual field on the project_items entity to calculate the sum of a float from the associated item_type table and a float from the project_items table:

```
protected function _getTotalItemEffort()
{
    $adjustment = $this->_properties['item_effort_adjustment'];
    $baseline = $this->_properties['item_type']->item_effort_baseline; //this works fine when used in project_items view, but causes error when referenced in project view
    return $adjustment + $baseline;
}
```

I can use this virtual field in the 'projects' view and it works fine

```
    <tr>
        <th><?= __('Total Item Effort') ?></th>
        <td><?= $this->Number->format($projectTemplate->total__item_effort) ?></td>
    </tr>
```

HOWEVER - if I try and use this in another virtual function on the project entity, I get the errors below BUT the errors are reported on the virtual function above that works fine.

```
protected function _getTotalBuildEffort()
{
    $effort = 0;
    foreach ($this->project_items as $item) {
        $effort = $effort + $item->total_build_effort; //this causes errors
    }
   return $effort;;
}
```

then I get errors

Notice (8): Undefined index: item_type [APP/Model/Entity/ProjectTemplateItem.php, line 49]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Model/Entity/ProjectTemplateItem.php, line 49]
Notice (8): Undefined index: item_type [APP/Model/Entity/ProjectTemplateItem.php, line 49]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Model/Entity/ProjectTemplateItem.php, line 49]

I am at a loss

Comment: Please check your example code again, there seems to be quite a few mistakes, like `projects` not being associated, double `_` in property name, referring to the wrong vitual property... Also include the code that actually reads the data, and a dump of the entity/data-structure would probably be useful too.

Comment: Also, whenever receiving errors, please always post the complete error message including the _full_ stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP!